# Prove L is not a regular language (A Finite State Automaton cannot accept it)

Tags: formal-languages, automata, regular-language

$$\mathscr L = \{x \in \{0,1\}^* \mid \text{there is a } y \in \{0,1\}^* \text{ such that } x = yy\}$$

How can I prove that this is not a Regular language? I tried using proof by contradiction but cannot manage to find a solution.

Comment: The [pumping lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages) would help you dramatically - do you know it? Intuitively, it says that finite state automata cannot "count".

Answer (score 0):

Hint- is $L^{\prime} = \{ 0^{n}1^{n} : n \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\} \}$ regular? What happens when you take $w \in L^{\prime}$? Is $ww \in \mathcal{L}$?